# Unexpected identifier with await: Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I should query a MongoDB and find all elements of a collection called *location* and store the results in a variable.
I have three scripts: **location.js** (in *models/location*), **fetcher.js** (in *fetch/fetcher*) and **test.js**;

> **location.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema

var locationSchema = new Schema({
    latitude: String,
    longitude: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('location', locationSchema)
```

> **fetcher.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Location = require('../models/location')

// set Promise provider to bluebird
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird')
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb')

exports.findAll = async () => {
    let query = await Location.find()
    return query
}
```

> **test.js**

```
const Location = require('./models/location')
const fetcher = require('./fetch/fetcher')
let items= await fetcher.findAll()
console.log(items[0].latitude)
```

When calling *node test.js* I receive this message:

```
 let items = await fetcher.findAll();
                   ^^^^^^^
 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:533:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:575:3`
```

If I remove the **await** keyword the error doens't appear anymore, but the result is     `Promise { <pending> }`.

I'm new in javascript and Node.js, and I don't master the asynchronus calls. Could you tell me where I wrong and how to solve this problem?

**Note**: I have the version Node v8.1.2

Comment: Hi @s.dallapalma, you should use `await` operator inside `async` function, `await` can not be used alone, at least I didn't heard about that use case

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak make that an answer, because you're right :D

Comment: @ŁukaszSzewczak await is present also in the findAll function, so why if I remove it the result is still "Promise {<pending>}"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved. Just call `let items= await fetcher.findAll()` inside an **async** function, like suggested by @ŁukaszSzewczak. So, I've updated my code to

```
async function doSomething(){
    let items= await fetcher.findAll()
    console.log(items[0].latitude)
    // Other code with variable items here ...
}
```